# How can I configure an .htaccess of a sub-directory so that it COMPLETELY ignores the .htaccess of any parent directories?

Tags: .htaccess

How can I configure the .htaccess of a sub-directory so that it COMPLETELY ignores the .htaccess of any parent directories?

Not just any rewrite rules, but EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't put a comment

but will using this will work:

in your folder create a .htaccess and put this code:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

or

in your main .htaccess file you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/?
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am using flask application on addon domain, main domain is wordpress site
the .htaccess rule is bellow

for addon domain

```
RewriteEngine off
PassengerAppRoot "/home/t0g5bface7dae/<yourfoldername>"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/t0g1bfae7dae/virtualenv/<yourfoldername>/3.8/bin/python"
```

and for main domain .htccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```